# Reading columns from csv with no labels in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
15.55   28.65   2
14.9    27.55   2
14.45   28.35   2
14.15   28.8    2
13.75   28.05   2
```

I would like to read it and save it as X,Y, Clusters.

I tried the following but I don't get any data

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

X = column(data, 0)
X = np.asarray(X)
Y = column(data,1)
Y = np.asarray(Y)
```

Comment: @timgeb just save the result into this names

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], it's unclear what the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: @timgeb The output is the list of the first coulmn and the second column, the third column, that's it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `header=None` and specify the `names` argument:

```
from io import StringIO

x = """15.55   28.65   2
14.9    27.55   2
14.45   28.35   2
14.15   28.8    2
13.75   28.05   2"""

# replace StringIO(x) with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), delim_whitespace=True,
                 header=None, names=['X', 'Y', 'Clusters'])

print(df)

       X      Y  Clusters
0  15.55  28.65         2
1  14.90  27.55         2
2  14.45  28.35         2
3  14.15  28.80         2
4  13.75  28.05         2
```

Then use `df['X']`, `df['Y']` or `df['Clusters']` as appropriate. In most cases, there's no additional *need* to convert to lists or arrays, though these operations are possible:

```
df['X'].tolist()  # convert series to list
df['X'].values    # convert series to NumPy array
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify you have no header, in your code, then you can get the series out of the dataframe, and if you absolutely need the list, you can convert it with `tolist()`

Here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sof.csv', header=None)
X, Y, Clusters = df[0], df[1], df[2]
print(X.tolist())
```

Output :

```
[15.55, 14.9, 14.45, 14.15, 13.75]
```